# How can I find namespace in xaml?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, winui-3

If you look at SettingsPage.xaml in a project created by TemplateStudio, you will find the following code: It doesn't work if I write the same code on the project I created without TemplateStudio. How can I find namespace Microsoft.UI.Xaml?

I'm working on the WinUI3 project.

```
<Page xmlns:xaml="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml">
    <RadioButton>
        <RadioButton.CommandParameter>
            <xaml:ElementTheme>Light</xaml:ElementTheme>
        </RadioButton.CommandParameter>
    </RadioButton>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the Doc: [Download and install the Windows UI Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started#download-and-install-the-windows-ui-library)

> In the NuGet Package Manager, select the Browse tab and search for
> Microsoft.UI.Xaml or WinUI. Select which Windows UI Library NuGet
> Packages you want to use (the Microsoft.UI.Xaml package contains
> Fluent controls and features suitable for all apps). Click Install.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't write that I'm working on the WinUI3 project.

Comment: You are working on the WinUI3 project, the WinUI3 project use `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` by default. So, you don't need to add `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` again.

Comment: The reason I couldn't find it was that I forgot "using:" in "xmlns:xaml="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml". Regardless of this, I'm a newbie in stackoverflow, and in this case, would it be right to delete this question?